# Parameters of open(): Everyone should have all access to file & should be truncated on creation

Tags: c++, linux, file-handling

I want to create a file in Unix that allows everyone all access.
If the file already exists, it should be truncated to be empty.

After reading through the open man page, I have following call. Just wanted to confirm if its the right way to do it.

```
int fd;
int flags = O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC;
/* Set umask to Octal 011 */
mode_t mode = S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH;
/* umask syscall alwasy succeeds. No need to save return value (previous umask value) */
umask(mode);
/* Set mode to Octal 666. open syscall will and mode with ~umask. 
   0666 & ~0011 = 0666 i.e. the mode we want to set.
*/
mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;
if ((fd = open(path.c_str(), flags, mode)) < 0) {
   return false;
} else {
  close(fd);
  return true;
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: As per Nikolai's comments, all access = Read & Write. I do not want everyone to be able to write to an executable file.

Comment: Do you really want execute permissions on a file anybody can write to?

Comment: The mode is anded with the umask.  So what you have written will not do what you want.

Comment: @Nikolai: Thanks for pointing out - I only want read + write.

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks for that! I can't believe I missed out the umask part. Anyway, I edited the question. Comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can guarantee the file creation mode is to explicitly zero out your umask before calling `open`, because the `mode` argument is NANDed against your umask.

It's probably best to simply set your file mode *after* you `creat` it.

Comment: By globally changing the `umask`, the program may be overriding the user's wishes, so it's really better to use `fchmod(3)` on each file with special requirements after the fact.

Comment: As I said, it's probably best to explicitly set the file mode after creation.

Comment: Yes, I was agreeing with you and adding a rationale (and surreptitously introducing `fchmod()` instead of `chmod()`).